# Access JSON response data in jQueryUI autocomplete callback

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI autocomplete to search a MySQL database.  When user presses enter in the search field, I want to populate a div with the result(s) returned from DB.

The code works and does return an autocomplete list of suggestions.

**However, I cannot understand how to use the JSON data returned in the `select:` function, for example to access the `title` and `author` fields returned in the JSON object. See the indicated alert() line in the jQuery code sample.**

`ui.item` alerts as [object Object]

`ui.item.title` alerts as undefined.

What else can I try?
Also, is `item` the correct label to use? If so, why? Where does that come from (I used `item` because it was consistently used in several examples I reviewed.)

**My jQuery:**

```
$('#srxbks').autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete_test.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('You chose: ' + ui.item);   <=== THIS LINE <===
        var out = 'Title: ' + ui.item.title + '<br>';
        out += 'Author: ' + ui.item.author + '<br>';
        $('.booksTableDIV').val(out);
    }
});
```

**My PHP:**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$term = strip_tags($_GET['term']);//retrieve search term sent by autocomplete

$qstring = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `title` LIKE '%" .$term. "%'";
$query = mysql_query($qstring) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $row['title']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['title']));
    $row['bid']=(int)$row['bid'];
    $row_set[] = $row['title'];
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give an exact answer without knowing what the JSON response is.

Alert isn't a good way to view javascript objects as you noticed. Try using `console.log` to inspect the object in the browser's developer console. This will help you find the right syntax.

To access the developer console...

- ... in Chrome, in the menu, go to View > Developer Tools
- ... in Firefox, in the menu, go to Tools > Web Developer > Web Console
- ... in IE, ... not sure... I'm on a Mac right now. It should be something like the above. I think it is also accessible by F12

In each of those, there should be a console tab to view log messages recorded using `console.log`.

I suspect that you will just need to do something like `ui.item[0]` or `ui.item.title`... but again, I cant be sure without the JSON data.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me get closer to a solution. However, I now have a new (related) question, [which I posted separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068136/jqueryui-autocomplete-json-not-returning-expected-data)

Comment: Glad it helped. Looks like your other question is answered too. Congrats.