# jQueryUI autocomplete JSON not returning expected data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Using jQueryUI autocomplete to search a MySQL database. When user presses enter in the search field, I want to populate a div with the result(s) returned from DB.

The code works and does return an autocomplete list of suggestions.

**However, the JSON data returned in the select: function is not what I expected.**

In the PHP code sample below, the query requests all fields from the database related to each title matched by the query. There should have been other fields, like author, bid, isbn, genre, etc. -- however, only the `title` field was returned.

Google Chrome's console looks like this:

```
Object {item: Object}
  item: Object
    label: "Much Obliged Jeeves"
    value: "Much Obliged Jeeves"
    __proto__: Object
  Object {label: "Much Obliged Jeeves", value: "Much Obliged Jeeves"}
```

Where are the other fields?

**My jQuery:**

```
$('#srxbks').autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete_test.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui);
        console.log(ui.item);
        console.log(ui.item.label);

        //Not working:
        var out = 'Title: ' + ui.item.title + '<br>';
        out += 'Author: ' + ui.item.author + '<br>';
        $('.booksTableDIV').val(out);
    }
});
```

**My PHP:**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$term = strip_tags($_GET['term']);//retrieve search term sent by autocomplete

$qstring = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `title` LIKE '%" .$term. "%'";
$query = mysql_query($qstring) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $row['title']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['title']));
    $row['bid']=(int)$row['bid'];
    $row_set[] = $row['title'];
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: There's only label and value properties in the object though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your PHP is only outputting the title variable and not the bid variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to be sure all your variables are included in the returning array. Your PHP is the part having an issue, your are not transferring the variables to JSON correctly. Your jQuery is fine. The following is what you need to do for each extra variable you wish to send back to your jQuery.

```
// Initialize your variables here
$returns = array();
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // Format your variables here
    $row['title']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['title']));
    $row['bid']=(int)$row['bid'];

    // Enter results into JSON array here
    $returns[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $returns[$i]['bid'] = $row['bid'];
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($returns);
```

Comment: Alternatively you can try something like `$returns[] = $row;` at the end.

Comment: Thanks very much. `Following comments are for future readers:` Foo_Chow is correct that I needed to specify the title while making the array, as in: `$returns['title'] = $row['title'];`. However, adding the other fields at this point *adds them to the autocomplete dropdown, which is not desirable.* Instead, when user presses Enter, I will use the returned title data to make an ajax call in the `select:` function, and use Foo_Chow's exact code in *that* PHP file to return all desired fields and update the results DIV. Thank you again, Foo Chow, for your help. +1 and accept.